# Is it possible to average models with different link functions?

Tags: link-function, model-averaging

While I can compare models that have different link functions in terms of AIC/BIC weights, I think it's impossible to use those weights to create an averaged model. Am I right in believing this?

Comment: It depends what you mean by "averaging". You're right that you shouldn't average the coefficients: this would be meaningless. But you can average their predictions, with a little bit of care.

Comment: I can see that.